# Geometry of Induced Metric Space of Unweighted Bipartite Graphs

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, bipartite-graphs

Every unweighted graph $G=(V,E)$ induces a *discrete* metric space $(V,d)$, where the distance function $d$ can be defined as

$
d(x,y)=\text{shortest path between }x\text{ and }y
$

Let's consider the following cases:

- $G$ is a path: then the induced metric space has an Euclidean-like geometry
- $G$ is a circle: then the induced metric space has properties of a spherical geometry
- $G$ is a tree: then the induced metric space has properties of a hyperbolic geometry

Now, for the case that $G$ is *bipartite*. Do you know about any work connecting the induced metric spaces of bipartite graphs to some geometry?

In other words: which manifold can be viewn as a continuous analogue of bipartite graphs?

---

For instance, complex networks could be shown to be connected to hyperbolic geometry.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.5169.pdf

Comment: What is the meaning of *"Euclidean-like geometry"*?

Comment: @Guido That means that the distances between points behaves as if they were on the euclidean manifold (a line in the case of a path).

Comment: So you are not considering the discrete metric space induced by $G$, but the metric graph which consists of the quotient of copies of $[0,1]$ for each edge, glued at the endpoints, no?

Comment: @GuidoA. I'm sorry, I did not understand what you mean by this. You might be right. Sorry if my explanation is not clear enough.